# Why do I get 'undefined' when i find offset of div in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is my code which I used.

**HTML:**

```
<div #fixed>adsfgheasfygeasfyguewrtu</div>
```

**ts:**

```
@ViewChild('fixed') menuElement: ElementRef;

@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
handleScroll(){
    const windowScroll = window.pageYOffset;
    console.log(this.menuElement.nativeElement.offsetTop;)
}
```

Comment: your code seems fine except a typo in console statement. Can you replicate the problem on Stackblitz?